# How does parseFloat() work when the string contains non-numeric characters?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having a problem when executing `parseFloat()` - I don't understand why it produces the following outputs:

```js
document.write(parseFloat("6e2") + "<br />"); //output is 600 why?
document.write(parseFloat("6b2") + "<br />"); //output is 6 why?
document.write(parseFloat("6c2") + "<br />"); //output is 6 why?
```

Could you tell me how the script is working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`6e2` produces 600 because it's treating your input as scientific notation.

6e2 == 6 x 10<sup>2</sup> == 600

The other two produce 6 because `parseFloat` parses the 6, then gets to input it isn't able to convert to a number, so it stops, and returns the result found so far.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

> parseFloat is a top-level function and is not associated with any
>   object.
>
> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat
>   returns NaN.
>
> For arithmetic purposes, the NaN value is not a number in any radix.
>   You can call the isNaN function to determine if the result of
>   parseFloat is NaN. If NaN is passed on to arithmetic operations, the
>   operation results will also be NaN.

Comment: what the character "E" is special character ? 6e2 = 6 x 10^2; so, E = 10 right?if right? how can?any documentation or reference for that...

Comment: Funny that those W3Schools docs aren't quite right. It isn't required that the first character be a number. If there are leading spaces, it will look past those. +1 though. :)

Comment: @MohamadSofiyan - yes, essentially.  If it reads 6e2 it will be smart enough to realize that you're using scientific notation.

Comment: MDN has [a better description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (of course). ;)

Comment: @RightSaidFred - thank you.  As I've said, I always learn something when you're around.  Updating my answer again.

Comment: Looks like I was a little to quick to criticize W3Schools. They do have a note lower down that leading and trailing spaces are allowed. Still MDN gives a bit more detail.

Comment: @david: He just redeemed himself.

Comment: @david - I'm converted to MDN now :)

Comment: huzzah! I will remove the downvote, but you're still referring to it as 'the docs' which is lies, it's just a reference site. The real docs would be section 9.3.1 of http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @David You're right.  The description is more accurate now.  Incidentally, when I was first learning html/javascript W3Schools was my goto place for info.  I guess I can grow up now :)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble @Adam. I should've just let it be in the first place. :(

Comment: @Adam I used it too :( till I started noticing that some of the stuff they have is... wrong, it just doesn't work. Not to mention it's full of bad practices. It's a real pity that they're so widely used.

Comment: @Right - it was no trouble at all.  In fact, you reminded me of an answer I needed to upvote.

Comment: @AdamRackis so 6 = 6 x 10 ^ 0; right?i'm still confuse with character "E". b or c is not same with E...sorry i'm newbie for this..:(

Comment: @MohamadSofiyan - yes, 6e0 is 6, since anything to the zeroth power is one, so 6 x 10^0 == 6 x 1 == 6.  The character E is treated as an exponent.  the characters b and c are treated as text, which can't be parsed, which causes pareseFloat to stop and return what it has so far.

Comment: i'm sorry can you give me the list of exponen character?i'm still looking for that...

Comment: @MohamadSofiyan - as far as I know, only e and E are the exponent characters.

Answer (score 2):

`parseFloat()` function determines if the first character in the specified string is a number. If it is number then it parses the string until it reaches the end of the number, and it returns the number as a number, not as a string.

so parseFloat("6b2") returns 6.

so parseFloat("6c2") returns 6.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, it is because it treats e as an exponent symbol (^)

The other two are only 6 because it ignores the rest once the numbers have ended

Comment: well technically it sees it as `*10^` otherwise you would get 36