# test if a string is a valid float in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, nan, parsefloat

I want to test if a string can be cast as a float. I have been trying to use parseFloat to achieve this.

```js
console.log(!isNaN(parseFloat("10000"))); // should return true
console.log(!isNaN(parseFloat("100T0"))); // should return false (but doesn't)
```

[Turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425524/how-does-parsefloat-work-when-the-string-contains-non-numeric-characters) that parseFloat just stops reading a string as soon as it hits a character that's not a digit, then returns whatever it has passed over so far.  So `parseFloat("100T0")` actually returns `100` and not `NaN`.

What's a better js test to see if a string can be cast as a float?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no one built-in operation provided by default in JavaScript that matches a reasonable "is this string a number" definition (to my mind, anyway). You can get close with `Number`, unary `+`, or implicit conversion (just passing the string into `isNaN` directly), with the caveat that they all do the same thing, which includes considering `""` to be `0`:

```js
// Number
console.log(!isNaN(Number("10000"))); // true
console.log(!isNaN(Number("100T0"))); // false
console.log(!isNaN(Number("")));      // true (!)

// Same as implicit (here triggered with a unary +)
console.log(!isNaN(+"10000")); // true
console.log(!isNaN(+"100T0")); // false
console.log(!isNaN(+""));      // true (!)


// Same as implicit
console.log(!isNaN("10000")); // true
console.log(!isNaN("100T0")); // false
console.log(!isNaN(""));      // true (!)
```

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) to a related question goes into your options in detail.

Consequently, you can either do a regular expression (be sure to allow for scientific notation!) or a check for `""` up-front:

```js
function toNumber(str) {
  str = String(str).trim();
  return !str ? NaN : Number(str);
}
console.log(!isNaN(toNumber("10000"))); // true
console.log(!isNaN(toNumber("100T0"))); // false
console.log(!isNaN(toNumber("")));      // false
```

Answer (score 9):

You won't get what you expect with **[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**, because it tries to parse `100T0` and returns `100`, so it's a valid `Number`.

Instead of using **[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)** you can just use regex, to check if the given `string` is only composed of numbers.

This is **[the regex `/^\-?[0-9]+(e[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/XLujYH/1)** you need, and this is how should be your code:

```
function isItNumber(str) {
  return /^\-?[0-9]+(e[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(str);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function isItNumber(str) {
  return /^\-?[0-9]+(e[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(str);
}

console.log(isItNumber("10000")) // should return true
console.log(isItNumber("100T0"))
console.log(isItNumber("10e5"))
console.log(isItNumber("100.50"))
```

Comment: Although I did not note this in the question, it needs to handle decimal points

Comment: @rvictordelta I edited the answer, with an updated regex.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with a regular expresion:

```
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('0');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('1000');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('10E0');
false
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('1000.E');
false
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('1000.1');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('1.1000');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('.1000');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('1000.');
false
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('-.1');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('-1000.1');
true
> (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test('-1000');
true
```

With a function:

```
function isValidFloat(str) {
    return (/^-?[\d]*(\.[\d]+)?$/g).test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another idea in psuedocode

```
1) Loop through string substrings (imitating parseFloat)
2) Get the substring that parseFloat stops at
3) Compare this substring to the original
```

### Old psuedocode - does not work totally - maybe with modifications

What you can do is this (psuedocode)

```
if (parseFloat (value)).toString() <> value then
   you know that the parse float only converted part of the value
```

Basically you are saying that string > float > (back to) string should give the same string if the conversations work "correctly".

Comment: Agreed. Edit with a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex to match only float format strings. Hope this helps.

```js
const reg = /^-?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$/g;

console.log("Should match");
console.log("123.2".match(reg));
console.log("12.000".match(reg));
console.log("-12.000".match(reg));

console.log("Should not match");
console.log("123".match(reg));
console.log("123a123".match(reg));
console.log("1e2".match(reg));
```